# Select data from database from a list via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
Table 1

Has list of car types

Sports
Sedan
Truck

Table 2 stores Id of car type with other data
```

When the user goes to the UI, user will select a date and select a car from the drop down list.

```
Date                             Drop down
1/1/2017                      Sports, Sedan, Truck
1/2/2017                      Sports, Sedan, Truck
```

When the user comes in first time, i want to load all the car types(from table 1_, if the user has selected a car type and saved it(load all the values from table 1, but set the saved one as selected), for example

```
1/1/2017                      Sedan (Select Sedan as default, load also Sports, Truck)
1/2/2017                      Truck (Select Truck as default ,load also Sports, Sedan)
```

then when i reload the page, i want Sedan to be selected.

I am having tough time achieving this.

```
<select id="carTypes" name="carTypes" ng-model="item.CarType">
   <option ng-repeat="o in Cars" value="{{o.Id}}" ng-selected="{{item.CarType==CarTypes[$index]}} ">{{o.Name}}</option>
   </select>
```

Above code selects same car type for all the rows.

CarTypes - object containing Id of the car type.
Cars - object containing cartype Id, name etc.

How can we implement this?

Comment: So what do u want?

Comment: the above code only shows one of your dropdowns. Could you please show a little more of your template (and possibly controllers) to get a better context?

Comment: My understanding is you need to retain the value of car type after you load the page. To do that, you need to use `localStorage`. When user selects the car type, save that value in `localStorage`. When you load the page, check for value in `localStorage`. If yes, show that selected by default in the list. Hope this helps.